# Django Group_By and SUM query

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to make a sumarized inventory report. To make that possible I have my model like this:

```
class Inventario(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(default=0,decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    ubicacion = models.ForeignKey(Ubicacion, null=True, blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.producto.item
```

In SQL-RAW i will make something like `SELECT producto.nombre as item, sum(cantidad) as cantidad,... FROM Inventario GROUP BY item` with the correct JOIN of course

And I will obtain something like:

```
|Item------- | Cantidad|
|PROD1       | 20      |
|PROD2       | 10      |
```

Instead of

```
|Item------- | Cantidad|
|PROD1       | 5       |
|PROD1       | 5       |
|PROD1       | 10      |
|PROD2       | 9       |
|PROD2       | 1       |
```

I want to make it using django way, actually I have

```
productos = Inventario.objects.filter(cantidad__gt=0).aggregate(Sum('cantidad'))
```

And this returns me only `cantidad_sum:30`

**UPDATE**
I get now the GROUP BY with this code

```
query = Inventario.objects.all().query
query.group_by = ['inventario_inventario.producto_id']
productos = QuerySet(query=query, model=Inventario)
```

but now I dont know how to make the "SUM" function :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `annotate` instead of `aggregate`. `aggregate` summarizes the entire queryset, whereas `annotate` generates values for each group. E.g.,

```
productos = Inventario.objects.filter(cantidad__gt=0).values('producto').annotate(sum_cantidad=Sum('cantidad'))
```

Check out the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset) for more details.

Comment: I have already tried annotate, but this still returns the entire table, like if there wasn't any GROUP_BY

Comment: Ah sorry -- you're right. Try to chain ".values('producto')" first -- that should give you the grouping. I updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: The `values`makes the magic, but... i get the producto's Id, do you know how to get one value from the Foreign key? like producto.item? or producto.description? Thanks

Comment: Answering  myself, i can get the foreign key value, typing `producto__item` like normal way... Thank you so much @Sohan Jain